# Convert negative times in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, data-conversion

I have an csv file full of time differences, some positive and some negative. I need to be able to work with each of these almost 300 variables in R (see image for an excerpt). I've tried various things but so far was unable to convert them to time values in R.

[image: Times]

Comment: Which things have you tried? You should explain them in the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read and include features from [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), especially the part about reproducing and pasting your data. The dataset is not available for us to demonstrate with; think of using a smaller example that can be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you could use `ifelse()` to create a covariate for negative vs positive values

Assuming your data set is named `d`

```
d$neg_vs_pos <- iselse(d$values<0,0,1)
```

Now, `d$neg_vs_pos==0` for all negative values and `d$neg_vs_pos==1` all positive values.

So, you can use a `subset`

```
neg_val <- subset(d,d$neg_vs_pos==0)
pos_val <- subset(d,d$neg_vs_pos==1)
```

However, not entirely sure what you'are asking.

Did this solve the problem?